# How do I download OS X Lion on my PC?

Tags: mac, installation, osx-lion

I want to upgrade my Snow Leopard machine (which is somewhere else) to Lion OS X.  In the Apple app store, the Lion OS X download isn't available on my Windows PC (it only shows iPad/iPod software).

I want to download the disk image using *this* (Windows PC) computer and transfer the installer to USB after download.

Is this possible?

Comment: **You have to download the image using an Apple computer.**

Comment: Ok, [it sounds like that's the answer](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only legally download it on a mac running 10.6.8 or higher, not on a pc or linux

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from the App Store within Snow Leopard. Update your installation to the latest version through Apple menu -> Software Updates... The Mac App Store should be included in the update. Reboot, and open it up from your Dock. Find OS X Lion and you can get it from there.

Alternatively, update Snow Leopard with the 10.6.8 Update Combo from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399. It includes all previous updates as well as the current one.

(Any particular reason you can't get it from your Mac?)

Answer (score -3):

You might be able to fool the software by changing the user agent string in your browser.

In firefox you can do this with the plugin 'user agent switcher'.

This used to be a useful trick back when a few webshites only worked if the browser claimed to be IE, but it is getting useful again when downloading software from very 'helpful' websites.

Comment: You don't use a browser to download the OS X Lion installer..

Comment: I assume the apps store was a browser based process. A surprising lot of apps are, and that has some advantages like easy updating). But it seems I assumed incorrectly.  Thanks @slhck.