# Is it possible to install Mac OS X Lion on a laptop having AMD Processor?

Tags: osx-lion

I have a laptop with AMD A8 processor, is it possibe to install Mac OS X lion on it using retail DVD ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download OS X Lion on my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/444090/how-do-i-download-os-x-lion-on-my-pc)

Answer (score 4):

Technically it is [possible](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/01/look-at-state-of-amd-hackintoshing.html), although it is not [legal](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf).

> you are granted a limited, non- exclusive license to install, use and
>   run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple- branded
>   computer at any one time.

It is also not nearly as stable as a true Mac would be.

If you want an inexpensive (By apple Standards) taste of the Mac environment, I would buy a [Mini](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/). ~$200 for a used one is possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. The [OS X license](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx1073.pdf) prohibits installing it on non-Apple hardware. There are no Apple-branded laptops with AMD processors. There are various different clauses for different license types, but they all contain this restriction:

"... you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single **Apple-branded** computer at any one time."

"... to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial use, one (1) copy of the
Apple Software directly on each **Apple-branded computer** running Mac OS X Snow Leopard
or Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control"

Answer (score 1):

No.  Legally, OSX can only be installed on Mac hardware.  There are "Hackintoshes" out there, however, they run on very specific PC hardware - all with Intel processors.

Comment: Ohh didn't know about the legalities. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Keltari I remember some "Hackintoshes" being installed on AMD CPU (since they have the same instruction set), however it involved heavy modification to the underlying system. This and coupled with the legal issues make this answer just for record.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, yes... I added an answer stating exactly that. Hackintoshes have all sorts of problems if you step away from specific chipsets as I recall, and AMD is even further out of the box of things that work. But it is possible, just not legal.

Comment: @AthomSfere and in all, that was the question asked. Is it possible? Yes. Is it legal? **No**.